# Boostrap nav menu immediately disappearing on click on mobile/small screen size

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, navbar

I have recently noticed that, when my bootstrap navbar for my layout file switches to the mobile-friendly, collapsed variant, that the button for expanding/showing the navigation links is acting very strangely, and in doing so, it is completely unusable.

When I click on the button to expand the menu, it expands, shows the animation for opening up long enough to display every item in the list, and then immediately shuts itself.

A second click simply displays a short animation with a white line appearing - my best guess is that this is the closing animation playing, but without a menu to close.

After the second click, the behavior repeats in that same pattern.

I'm not sure what I would have changed that could be causing this, other than perhaps messing up the ordering of my javascript/css loading, but the searches I've done on that front seem to be consistent with what I am doing in my bundles, here:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js*",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/navbarLinksCurrentColor.js",
            "~/Scripts/ajaxCallWithLoadingIcon.js"
            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                  "~/Content/styles.css"));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

The bundle configuration is loaded in the standard manner, inside of Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        if (!File.Exists(LogFilePath))
            File.Create(LogFilePath);
    }
```

These bundles are loading in this manner in my layout view, here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        @{Html.RenderPartial("NavigationMenu");}
    </header>
    <div class="body-content container-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    <div id="processing"
         class="processingIcon">
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
    </div>
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the layout view calls a partial view to render the navigation menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        @*I originally was using the 4-span style that I've seen 
        commonly for the collapse button, but switched to a glyphicon
        approach to simplify things as well as see if it would fix the
        issue - it did not, so I don't think it is relevant to this issue*@
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" 
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarLinks"></button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Hire Right Testing</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarLinks">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("New Clients", "NewClients", "Client")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Build a Custom Test", "Index", "CustomSolutions")</li>
                @*More links here...*@
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The issue was occurring prior to me migrating this out into its own file, so I don't believe that is the cause of the strange behavior.

The only other case which seemed similar to this was a case where the solution ended up being a mismatch between the Bootstrap css and js files, which I don't think is the case as I have uninstalled and then reinstalled the Bootstrap nuget package (currently using version 3.3.7, the current latest version).

Package Versions:
Bootstrap - 3.3.7 (also tried: 3.3.5)

jQuery - 3.1.1 (also tried: 1.12.4, 2.0.0, 2.2.4, 3.0.0.1)

jQuery.Validation - 1.16.0 (also tried: 1.15.1)

Final thought: Not sure if the _references.js file would matter for this at all, but here is that file, as well:

```
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.js" />
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="ajaxcallwithloadingicon.js" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap.min.js" />
/// <reference path="customsolutions/categoryfilterpartial.js" />
/// <reference path="customsolutions/customsolutionspartial.js" />
/// <reference path="customsolutions/index.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.8.3.js" />
/// <reference path="navbarlinkscurrentcolor.js" />
/// <reference path="orderdetailsupdates.js" />
/// <reference path="replacingdivcontents.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.matchmedia.addlistener.min.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.min.js" />
/// <reference path="showhidediv.js" />
/// <reference path="toggledivsandbuttons.js" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to find the part of my code which was causing this issue. I got to this answer by creating a new .NET MVC application using the template and experimenting with code copied over from the application which had the issue. None of the scripting/bundling appeared to be the issue, the actual problem was part of my css.

Some time back, I had apparently placed this block inside my main .scss file:

```
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
```

I do not remember why I placed this inside my css - but it was the sole cause of the nav menu issues.